# JQuery-Plugin-Tooltipster: "onlyOne" does not work if an Element with tooltip got child with additional tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

```
<div id="parent" title="parent tooltip" style="width: 500px">
    PARENT!
    <div id="child" title="child tooltip" style="width: 100px">
        CHILD!
    </div>
</div>
```

If you hover the child element directly, all cascaded tooltips will show.
Neither explicit setting of "onlyOne" nor a different delay for the child-tootlip will help.

Is it possible to show only the one from the child without writing own hover-triggers?

The jQuery code (using V 1.8.2) is as follows:

```
$("div").tooltipster({onlyOne: true, delay: 100});
```

---

After cleaning up my confusion and ignorance of the JQueryUI widget I will use this and do the styling again. But I want to use the tooltipster plugin in future because it offers some features I don't see with the widget. So the question remains unanswered...

https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/32

Comment: Where's the `jQuery` code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing an issue here with:

```
$('div').tooltip();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dwaddell/QUXKB/

What version of jQuery are you using, they may have fixed something as the tooltip plugin is rather new.